# How to rotate camera 90 degree with AIY Vision Bonnet?

Tags: google-aiy

I need to set camera rotation to 90 degree due to hardware constrains of the project I am building.

I have tried using PiCamera examples and set `camera.rotation = 90`. That rotates preview correctly, however inference stops working.

Setting `camera.rotation = 180` works and does not break inference.

Comment: Digging more into details of the Raspberry Pi Camera details I learned that the camera module can do only some minor processing. Specifically, flips (horizontal and vertical), line skipping, and pixel binning. Also rotation is always implemented by some combination of transposition and flips [source](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html). 180 rotation can be implemented just with hflip and vflip, that can occur on the camera module, but 90 and 270 require transposition, that normally happens on GPU, but vision kit runs before the GPU, thus it doesn't get full transformation

Comment: So my guess for the best way of getting 90/270 degree rotation is to simply embed it into the compute graph running on VPU